# Getting value from cell within dynamically generated table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table that is dynamically generated via JavaScript based on data from an SQL query.  The first cell contains a button that should retrieve the value in the 2nd cell within that row onclick.  For some reason, the jQuery onclick event is not firing.  No errors are being thrown in the browser.

HTML

```
...
for (var i=0; i<queryReturned.Result.length; i++) {
  var tableRow = document.createElement("tr");
  var cell = document.createElement("td");
  var button = document.createElement("button"); //Button gets added here
  button.type = "button"; 
  button.value = "Remove Alert";
  button.className = "buttonSelect"
  cell.appendChild(button);
  tableRow.appendChild(cell);
  //This loop creates the rest of the cells and fills in their data
  for (var j=0; j<Object.keys(queryReturned.Result[i]).length; j++) {
    var cell2    = document.createElement("td");
    var cellText = document.createTextNode(Object.values(queryReturned.Result[i])[j]);
    cell2.appendChild(cellText);
    tableRow.appendChild(cell2);
  }
  tableBody.appendChild(tableRow);
}
table.appendChild(tableBody);
table.setAttribute("border", "2");
body.appendChild(table);
...
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".buttonSelect").on('click',function(){
     var currentRow=$(this).closest("tr");
     var col2=currentRow.find("td:eq(1)").html();
     alert(col2); //alert for now to test if we grabbed the data
  });
});
```

Comment: Reword your event handler function like so: `$(document).on('click', '.buttonSelect', function(){ ... });` so it will work for dynamically added elements as well. (I'm not 100% sure though whether `$(this)` will be the same as in your version.)

Comment: Thanks @connexo.  That did the trick.  You should totally add that as an answer so I can give you due credit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reword your event handler function like so:

```
$(document).on('click', '.buttonSelect', function(){ ... });
```

so it will work for dynamically added elements as well.

Let us know how it goes!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly the main problem is that you need to use a delegated event handler to attach the `click` event to the `button` element.

Also, you're using an odd mix of JS and jQuery. You can massively simplify the table creation logic. Too. Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  var $table = $('<table />').appendTo('body'); // this wasn't in your code example, but should look like this

  queryReturned.Result.forEach(function(result) {
    var $tr = $("<tr />").appendTo($table);
    var $td = $("<td />").appendTo($tr);    
    $('<button class="buttonSelect">Remove Alert</button>').appendTo($td);

    for (var j = 0; j < Object.keys(result).length; j++) {
      $('<td />').text(result[j]).appendTo($tr);
    }
  }

  $(document).on('click', '.buttonSelect', function() {
    var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");
    var col2 = currentRow.find("td:eq(1)").html();
    alert(col2);
  });
});
```

Comment: This is very useful.  Yes, I'm a beginner with both so I've been piecing together whatever I can.  Thank you for the great suggestions!